# Is this a unicode or a str?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, pyyaml

I have a dictionary that I need to share from Python 3 to Python 2. I dumped it as JSON in P3 and then loaded in Python2. Finally I (thought I) converted to P2 string using `yaml.load`.

Now there is something that seems wrong to me.
I know that there are some unicode string(s) that are breaking a package.
I tried to find them using

```
[key  for key in my_dict if type(key) != str]
[]
```

Why then

```
'C%2B%2B' in my_dict
True
```

and

```
type('C%2B%2B')
unicode
```

is not caught? Why does the list comprehension think it is a string?

```
[type(key)  for key in my_dict if key == 'C%2B%2B']
[str]
```

Finally, is there a way I can convert it to str so that it will not break my code?

EDIT: ipython2 seems to have no consistent behavior on my computer:

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: `in my_dict.keys()` can (should) be `in my_dict`.

Comment: i get from `type('C%2B%2B')` `<type 'str'>`...

Comment: True, thanks! I'll make the change

Comment: @yoopoo this is odd. Please see attached images

Comment: @yoopoo is right, `type('C%2B%2B')` will be `str` in Python 2 and 3 (unless you did a `from __future__ import unicode_literals` as Jan-Philip notes).

Comment: @LevLevitsky not if he is using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in Python 2.

Comment: @Jan-Philip Yeah, just saw your answer. Good point!

Comment: My bad: I used the wrong import, now everything is a str, but I still get the error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found` which seems to suggest there is some sort of unicode problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep control over your data before *encoding* it to JSON. In Python 3, make sure all of the strings are unicode objects (i.e. of type `str`), and then write them to a JSON file using e.g. UTF-8 encoding. Then decode that file using the same codec in Python 2. The resulting string types must be `unicode`. The code snippets you are showing do not help much, it is unclear in which version of Python you executed each of the snippets shown (the `type('C%2B%2B') == unicode` case suggests that you are using Python 2 with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, the last snippet, however, is likely created from within Python 3). You *must* understand that type `str` in Python 2 is fundamentally different from `str` in Python 3.

Comment: you are right, I imported unicode_literals from future, trying to add compatibility. Also, everything here (except the original JSON) was created with Python2

Comment: @meto These problems are much simpler to solve and explain if you provide a minimal piece of code that we can directly execute. Your snippets/screenshots do not really help. The origin of your problem for sure is *i)* that you do not take the required amount of care about distinguishing the byte string and unicode string types in both, Python 2 and 3 and *ii)* that you do not take proper control of first encoding your unicode strings to a byte sequence representation and later decoding these sequences to unicode strings again. This is pretty straight-forward once you understand the process.